# error importing Dajaxice 'no module named "Dajaxice"'

Tags: python, dajaxice

I have followed this tutorial several times and double and triple-checked that I did it correctly:

http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

I am using Windows and have installed Dajaxice. I can enter the Django api and import `dajaxice` with no errors:

```
>>> import dajaxice
>>>
```

However, I am getting an error

> no module named Dajaxice

when trying to import anything from `dajaxice.core`. Here's the line in my *urls.py* causing the issue:

```
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
```

I am at a loss here. I have read every stack overflow answer on the subject, tried the tutorial several times, and have even tried reinstalling Dajaxice (as well as Dajax). Why is it that I can import `dajaxice` with no error but error out on `from dajaxice.core import foo`?

Here's the relevant parts of settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'project_view',
    'dajaxice',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    #"django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Do I need to add anything for STATIC_ROOT? That is empty.